# Expected a 'for-of' loop instead of a 'for' loop while doing modifications

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint, for-of-loop

I'm having problems with *TSlint* and understanding why the `for(i=0; ...)` loop is not longer permitted.

Let's assume I have a simple code like:

```
this.filters['1','2','3'....];
for (let i = 0; i < this.filters.length; i++) {
      if (this.filters[i] === '2') {
        this.filters = new_value;
      }
    }
```

which *TSlint* is asking me to convert it to *for-of*. However, using *for-of* is not going to work as I need to modify the value and the for-of does not allow to modify. I could use something like

```
for (const [i, el] of this.filters.entries()) {
```

but then I get a compilation warning 
*TypeScript* and Iterator: Type `'IterableIterator<T>'` is not an array type
and I do have to change the compilation options. Also, I could iterate over the `keys()` which I see a bit stupid having the `for(const i=0...)`

Can someone explain me why *TSlint* is still complaining about this and why is not allowing to use the `for(const i=0; ....)`

Furthermore, I just saw that if do this code in a *for-of*

```
this.filters['1','2','3'....];
for (let f of this.filters) {
      if (f === '2') {
        f = new_value;
      }
    }
```

I would end up with the same array as it is not modified after the loop, but however, if I have a similar approach but with objects

```
let filters = [{id:'1'},{id:'2'},{id:'3'}];
console.log(filters)
for (let f of filters) {
      if (f.id === '2') {
        f.id = 'toto';
      }
    }
console.log(filters)
```

Surprise, my array of objects is modified after the loop! Can someone explain me why ?

Thank you

I searched for the error and I saw it in github as an issue that was closed but I can't find the solution
https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/1813

Comment: `this.filters['1','2','3'....];` do you mean `this.filters = ['1','2','3'....];`?

Comment: Also, why do you want the index of the item? It seems that all you care about is each item's value, so a `for-of` seems appropriate.

Comment: Also weird to want to use const in the loop for the iterators

Comment: have you read https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/prefer-for-of/ also it's probably just your config rules that highlight it

Comment: The latter half of the question is unrelated to the first one - you are probably better off posting it as a separate one.

Comment: If any value in the array is `2`, you want to replace the whole array, but continue iterating at the same index? That seems strange.

Comment: Modifying the array while iterating is a bad idea, many bugs can creep in as you modify the code. What you are actually doing doesn't seem to make sense, reassign the entire array being iterated? Anyone else that has to modify that code will hate your for writing it that way ;) Suggestion, create a new array and modify/add new items to that.

Comment: Also, you are conflating questions. Are you asking about `for of` or why do you have different behavior with variables that point to primitives or objects? You should probably create separate questions that are more digestable. That makes your questions easier to answer and more helpful to others who may have the same question. For the sentence that actually has a question mark, here's the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/227299

Comment: I'm suggesting we close this as a dupe, if you have a question about the `for of`tslint rule, please ask another question focusing on that, not on the reference/value aspect that you seem to be unsure about

Comment: It was just a way to put the code fast. Yes, it was a typo this.filters = ['1','2','3'....].
What I want to say is if I want to modify only one value of the array, how the hell I do it using for-of. Omg, you care more about that the two questions are unrelated than actually answering them...

Comment: @Javier yes, we do. This is what makes SO the site where people go for answers, because each question has focus. If you conflate two questions, then the answers will be of lower quality because they won't be addressing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With strings you get following:

String is assigned to `f`. Then new value is reassigned to `f`: `f === '2'`. But string from array is not touched.

With objects:

Reference to object is assigned to `f`. Then object is being modified: `f.id = 'toto'`. Since array contains only reference to an object - we get modified object in array.

Basically the answer ends up with difference between reference type and value type variables.

In your case if `for (const [i, el] of this.filters.entries()) {` does not work because of ts settings, you could try:

```
arr.forEach((entry, index) => arr[index] = ...);
```

or something more ugly:

```
for(entry of arr) {
    arr[arr.indexOf(entry)] = ...;
}
```

Comment: I think this is potentially what the OP is asking, but their question is confusing and so is this answer. A runnable  example would help clarify. You can explain that in the loop, if you reassign a variable that points to a primitive, you're not going to modify what's in the array. Having said that, if this is what they are asking, this has been asked a thousand times before and should closed as a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/227299

Comment: Thank you Mendes, but actually Alex helped way more than you did. Thank you for the forEach solution. I do find it even less clear than using a normal for but the compiler does not complain.